# Does Dell Inspiron 15z (5523) touch screen compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: dell, laptop, inspiron, compatibility, touchscreen

I'm considering about buying Dell inspiron 15z (5523) laptop, but I'm not sure if touch screen of laptop will compatible with Ubuntu.
Also, because I couldn't know the model or company of touch screen, I couldn't find if it will be compatible with Ubuntu.

If someone has Inspiron 15z with touch screen, could you please give me an answer?
Thank you very much  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is compatible and it works during the installation of Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit which includes selecting/activating items on the screen <strike>but when I got into the actual operating system the activating items ceased to work but I can still move the cursor around.</strike>

Simple restart fixed me being unable to activate objects on the screen. So to answer that is a definite yes on it being compatible :) hope you have a fun time with your laptop.

Specs

Brand: Dell

Model: Inspiron 15z (touch)

Processor: Intel Core I7-3537U Ivybridge  2.0Ghz

RAM: 8GB DDR3

HDD 1: 500GB sata II (Seagate)

HDD 2: 32GB SSD (Samsung)